# Change cell color based on another cell color in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to change a particular cell color based on the specific cell color. (For ex: If A1 cell color is green then B1 background color should change to green if A2 cell color is red than B2 cell color should change to red. Kindly help me how to do that in google sheets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the reason for having google-apps-script tag for this question?

Comment: Is there a formula for changing A1, B1, etc green/red? Or are you just changing these manually?

Answer (score 2):

this is not possible as you imagine it. however, this is:

let's say that if:

A2 cell color is RED because it's not empty/has a number/has specific text... then you can set color to be RED on B2 if A2 not empty/has a number/has specific text...

in such case, you use so-called custom formula. example:

[image: 1]

also, you may be interested in: [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/c](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/team-color/ldggbboahhbelionpagpifdnkicagagg?utm_source=permalink)